# Azure function .Net 5 HTTP Trigger Post request Data limitation

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to Post a data that is more than 4 MB (4096 Bytes) to the Azure function using HTTP Trigger.

It is **timing out** .
Following is my code in Azure function

public static class SampleFunction
{
[Function("SampleFunction")]
public static async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,  "post")] HttpRequestData req,
FunctionContext executionContext)
{

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            

            await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);               
            
            ms.Position = 0;
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(ms);


            //..PRocess the file
        }


    }
}
```

}

I am using Postman as client with following configuration :

[image: Postman configuration]

[image: The test file of 4 MB]

I checked the Microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp

It refers to 100 MB limitation. Please let me know, what mistake I am doing ?

Comment: Your postman screenshot shows 500 status code(that means code error), not a timeout(408). Is your http trigger method being hit when you place breakpoints ?

Comment: The postman screen shot was to show the configuration. Please ignore the Status code.

Comment: I tried your sample code and i do not get 408. Have you tried putting breakpoints in your method and see that is being hit ? Also, what does "process the file does" ? Is it possible that that part is taking forever and times out ?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Have you used input file size more than 4 MB (4096 Bytes) ? When I did , the Azure function .Net 5 never got invoked. Please let me know , your findings and share the settings

Comment: Are you running into [this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#limits) specified in the docs ? 
*If a function that uses the HTTP trigger doesn't complete within 230 seconds, the Azure Load Balancer will time out and return an HTTP 502 error*

Comment: I was under the impression that you have tried my sample code and posted file size > 4 MB. Please try it and let me know the answer. I am aware that HTTP trigger has time limit. For any file < 4MB (even 3.9 MB) my logic gets executed within 10 secs.